# Replace image src in vml markup with globally available images using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, capybara, nokogiri, vml

Is it possible to find outlook specific markup via Capybara/Nokogiri ?

Given the following markup (erb `<% %>` tags are processed into regular HTML)

```
...
<div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect
        xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false"
        style="width:<%= card_width %>px;height:<%= card_header_height %>px;"
    >
        <v:fill type="tile"
            src="<%= avatar_background_url.split('?')[0] %>"
            color="<%= background_color %>" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
<div>
```

How can I get the list of `<v:fill ../>` tags ? (or eventually how can I get the whole comment if finding the tag inside a conditional comment is a problem)

I have tried the following

```
doc.xpath('//v:fill')
```

> *** Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError Exception: ERROR: Undefined namespace prefix: //v:fill

DO I need to somehow register the vml namespace ?

EDIT - following @ThomasWalpole approach

```
doc.xpath('//comment()').each do |comment_node|
  vml_node_match = /<v\:fill.*src=\"(?<url>http\:[^"]*)"[^>]*\/>/.match(comment_node)
  if vml_node_match
    original_image_uri = URI.parse(vml_node_match['url'])
    vml_tag = vml_node_match[0]
    handle_vml_image_replacement(original_image_uri, comment_node, vml_tag)
  end
```

My `handle_vml_image_replacement` then ends up calling the following `replace_comment_image_src`

```
def self.replace_comment_image_src(node:, comment:, old_url:, new_url:)
  new_url = new_url.split('?').first # VML does not support URL with query params
  puts "Replacing comment src URL in #{comment} by #{new_url}"
  node.content = node.content.gsub(old_url, new_url)
end
```

But then it feels like the comment is actually no longer a "comment" and I can sometimes see the HTML as if it was escaped... I am most likely using the wrong method to change the comment text with Nokogiri ?

Comment: You can set namespace as xpath() paramters but the problem is the comment. The comment content isn't accessible via xpath().

Comment: How can I access the comment ? couldn't find a lot of doc regarding comments in nokogiri ?

Comment: You can access the comments with XPath `//comment()` however IIRC nokogiri doesn't parse the contents of comments into further nodes (it's just text) so you wouldn't be able query against specific nodes within the comment.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip @ThomasWalpole but I'm struggling to find a way to replace the tag src attribute without messing up the whole thing...

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris You probably want `native_content=` instead of `content=`. The latter escapes the text being set while the former does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final code that I used for my email interceptor, thanks to @Thomas Walpole and @sschmeck for help along the way.

My goal was to replace images (linking to localhost) in VML markup with globally available images for testing with services like MOA or Litmus

```
doc.xpath('//comment()').each do |comment_node|
  # Note : cannot capture beginning of tag, since it might span across several lines
  src_attr_match = /.*src=\"(?<url>http[s]?\:[^"]*)"[^>]*\/>/.match(comment_node)
  next unless src_attr_match
  original_image_uri = URI.parse(src_attr_match['url'])
  handle_comment_image_replacement(original_image_uri, comment_node)
end
```

WHich is later calling (after picking an url replacement strategy depending on source image type) :

```
def self.replace_comment_image_src(node:, old_url:, new_url:)
  new_url = new_url.split('?').first
  node.native_content = node.content.gsub(old_url, new_url)
end
```